# How to lock Zoom Meeting in full screen

Tags: kiosk

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 for my sons for virtual learning and look to do so for the entire year.  Much of the time they are engaged in Zoom meetings, but of course, they like to open other applications, which is not allowed.  I am wondering if it is possible to lock a Zoom meeting in full screen and only allow exit with a password, essentially putting the computer into a kiosk mode with Zoom as the application.  This is not a dedicated device so I need to be able to switch it back to general purpose mode when appropriate.  Any pointers would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps creating dedicated Zoom username with Zoom setup in this session to fullscreen and auto restart. And use separate user with normal desktop session for everything else.

The limited user could run openbox or similar light window manager which will discourage your kids because all options will simply seem to have vanished :)